# Cant we use a PHP file directly like myhome.com/some.php?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, settings-api

i just want to add a php file into my site say www.mysite.com/some.php. I dont want to create any page using that php file as page template. All i want is to add a php file which as some php codes in it and redirects to my another page after successful access. I know it is possible and seen in many sites that they use it. How should I to do this???? any solution or at least an hint will help me.

Comment: There is nothing in a default WordPress install that would prevent you from placing a php file within your public html directory and accessing it directly.

Comment: @Milo But i saw some sites that they have .php files in their link with in the public html. They too use wordpress. If i cant, is there any way around to make it??

Comment: @Milo you should post that comment as an answer. In the current phrasing of the question, your comment answers it.

Comment: @ChipBennett so it is not possible to make a .php link???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're just looking for a basic [php include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

```
include '/some.php';
```

Just make sure the path is correct.  I've used this before no problem, php will interpret your included file as if it were part of the file including it.

... after reading your question again you may be asking for something even simpler, just link to your file from another page to access any resource, including php files, on your site.

Comment: Where should i use thad code include '/some.php'; ???

Comment: You would put that into one of your theme files (or your post if you're using a plugin that lets you use php in posts).  Maybe I'm not fully understanding what you are asking.

Comment: I guess yu got my question wrongly. What i asked was how to create a separate php file and to let the user access it (say www.example.com/download.php). by using this i can execute the php code when and only my user needs to download and by passing values via url (say www.example.com/download.php?file=jpg) I can customize the code and get different results.
Is that clear??

Comment: Yeah, that's clearer.  Cant you just make a regular link to  `www.example.com/download.php?file=jpg` somewhere on your page?  As far as I know wordpress will serve up files that exist on your domain before doing it's own url interpretation.  That's what the lines `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` mean that wordpress puts into the htaccess file when you set up permalinks.  you do have permalinks set up right?  Does that work for you?

Comment: I cant link it straightly. If i try to link my www.example.com/download.php , i am end up with 404 no page found error.
and i cant follow what u are tryna say with that code. Should I add that code in any part of my theme file???

Comment: Did you set your permalinks under wordpress settings?  If so wordpress should automatically add that code (and some more) to your .htaccess file (as long as wordpress can write to your files).  As long as that's in there then you shouldn't get a 404 - as long as /download.php exists in the root or where ever your link points to.  Does that work?

Comment: I tried to set but i dont know how to do. Could you explain it how??

Comment: It's under "settings" in the admin.
This discussion is too long and veering off of the initial question.  I tried moving this to the chat forum but you dont currently have enough reputation.  I suggest editing your initial question in light of what we've discussed so we can focus on the right answer to the right question.

Comment: oooppss..can we talk about this in mail??
if yu dont mind contact me on this id hitmyg@gmail.com
please dont feel like am disturbing yu...I am searchin solution for a very long time.yu r the only hope for me rite now.so please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

if that file is in your theme folder then :

```
include(get_bloginfo('template_directory').'some.php');
```

or if its in wordpress folder root :

```
include(site_url.'some.php');
```